# "'Image' object is not callable" when posting API object

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

**Update 2, 13th Jan:** After doing some bug searching and trying to post the object directly in the root API using json, I've come to the realisation that the *image* is what's giving me the posting error.

I used the HTML form to post an object and it gave me this error:

```
TypeError at /rats/

'Image' object is not callable
```

For context, I uploaded an image. Here are my serialisers for creating the object (rat) and for images:

```
class ImageSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    image = VersatileImageFieldSerializer(
        sizes='rat_headshot'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['name', 'image']
        
class RatSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    user         = serializers.CharField(source='user.username', required=False)
    userid       = serializers.CharField(source='user.id', required=False)
    body_colour  = BodyColourSerializer()
    eye_colour   = EyeColourSerializer()
    image        = ImageSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = rat
        exclude = ['bio']

    def create(self, data):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        print("I was here", data, request)
        return rat.objects.create(
            name = data["name"],
            body_colour = BodyColour(name=data["body_colour"]["name"]),
            eye_colour = EyeColour(name=data["eye_colour"]["name"]),
            # bio = data["bio"],
            image = Image(name=data["image"]["name"])(required=False),
            user = request.user,
        )
```

I've updated the title. Original title was "Can't manage to post an object via axios to django - possibly due to AnonymousUser object?", now it's " "'Image' object is not callable" when posting API object "

---

**Update 8th Jan:** I fixed the AnonymousUser error. Django wanted an ID but was instead getting the user class, I fixed it by changing `user = request.user` into `user = request.user.id`

However, I'm still unable to post the object. I'm getting the same res.data error as below. So now I'm not sure what's causing the error.

---

I'm trying to add a button in React which posts an object to django via axios when a user clicks on it. However, it seems like something's wrong backend.

Here's the button:

```
<button
            id="add-rat"
            type="button"
            className="btn homeButton"
            onClick={
              (e) => submit(e)
            }
          >
            Add rat
          </button>
```

And here's the axios, in the same page:

```
  const submit = (e) => {
    const name = "namee";
    const eyeColour = "Red";
    const bodyColour = "White";
    const bio = "hfff";
    const image = "lineart.PNG";
    const data = {
      name: name,
      eye_colour: eyeColour,
      body_colour: bodyColour,
      bio: bio,
      image: image,
    };
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addObject", data, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

This is my console output:

```
{name: 'namee',

 eye_colour: 'Red', body_colour: 'White', bio: 'hfff', image: 'lineart.PNG'}
myRats.js:86 {res: 'Error Accured'}
```

(myRats.js:86 btw, is console.log(res.data); )

Here's my `view` for the object:

```
class AddRat(APIView):
def post(self,request):
    data = request.data
    user = request.user
    print(data)
    try:
        user = rat( name = data['name'] , body_colour = data['bodyColour'] , eye_colour = data['eyeColour'],user= user,  bio = data['bio'] , image = data['image'])
        user.save()
        return Response({'res':"Rat Saved Successfully"})
    except:
        return Response({'res':"Error Accured"})

def get(self,request):
    user = request.user
    data = rat.objects.filter(user = user)
    data = RatSerializer(data, many = True)
    return Response({'data':data.data})
```

When I go to the url it's posting to, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /api/addObject
Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0000014641FD85B0>.
```

Could it possibly be due to that? What could be wrong?

Comment: The console error you are getting is self explanatory. Although you do pass the bearer token in your headers, you still get an anonymous user which of course doesn't have an integer id. Please have a look at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ to understand how DRF authentication works.

Comment: @Josewails I've read it a few times now but I don't understand my error. I'm new to these things. How do I fix so I don't get an anonymous user? Considering the token doesn't seem to be the issue here?

Comment: @Josewails I figured out how to fix the Anonymous user error, updated my post. However I'm still unable to post the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Anonymous User issue was solved by changing `user = request.user` into `user = request.user.id`

And my second issue, "'Image' object is not callable" was due to me putting (required=False) in another set of parenthesis, as if I was calling an Image as a function.
So I changed

```
image = Image(name=data["image"]["name"])(required=False)
```

into

```
image = Image(name=data["image"]["name"], required=False)
```